# What is the meaning of this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing

Can someone please paraphrase the whole paragraph?

> Since in past years when that term was not as much familiar, or earlier than the existence of nano-sized particles has been well-thought-out to be appropriate.

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352738907_Introduction_to_nanomedicine_an_overview)

Comment: It makes no sense. **Please give the source of the paragraph.**

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352738907_Introduction_to_nanomedicine_an_overview.        On page4

Comment: One may guess at the gist of the idea, especially when embedded within the rest of the paragraph, but this particular sentence is a mess and not well formed.

Comment: The authors are probably not native speakers of English.

Comment: It's maybe an ungrammatical time clause, definitely not a complete sentence, so it cannot be analyzed for meaning. It's word soup.